# what is the etymology of Hebrew word lasse‘irim לַשְּׂעִירִם

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, semitic-languages

Why would this be translated as a demon/goat?

I'm also unclear as to the lemma.  Is seems unrelated.  Is it שָׂעַר

Comment: The lemma is שָׂעִיר.

Answer (score 4):

In Hebrew, one-letter prepositions are not separated from the next word by a space. The lamed in לַשְּׂעִירִם is a preposition and therefore not part of the word that interests you, which is

שְּׂעִירִים

(the word has two yods), which is actually a homograph for two words:

1. a pluralis tantum meaning 'showers' (rains).
2. the plural of the word spelled sin ayin yod resh, which is an adjective meaning 'hairy, hirsute, pilose' and a noun meaning 'he-goat; satyr; goat demon'.

Comment: Sin ayin yod _mem_? Not resh?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet undoubtedly a typo. I've corrected with an edit. Otherwise this answer seems very good

Comment: Yup. You see that root all over and not without spiritual overtones. Hairy billy goats for sacrifices but also Elijah being a "lord of hair" in Kings :)

Comment: Indeed, a slip of the "pen."  Thank you for correcting it.